# Debugging R dataframe issues when inserting data to SQL server

Tags: r, sql-server

I have a `R` dataframe with 48 columns and around 25k rows.
I use `SQLquery` to insert rows into the SQL server.

I noticed that after 14k insertion to the database, I am getting an error like:

`"42000 8114 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to float."`

My question, in general, is there a standard process about how to debug the data or know which column is giving an issue?
I compared the data types of the columns between SQL server and R and it tends to look correct:

[image]

I can provide additional information but any insights on how to go about debugging such scenario?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I also wonder if `float` is the correct data type choice, it rarely is.

Comment: what would you suggest as datatype? I am surprised why it wouldn't be when it worked for 14000 rows...

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, so I can't comment on what you *should* be using, just that it's rare that `float` is the *right* choice. Are you dealing with exceptionally large or small values?

Comment: small values.. ..nothing bigger than 20.. This is such an annoying part of R... no relevant information is provided for debugging.

Comment: okay I got it fixed. There were some NA values in couple of numeric columns!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error was due to the fact that some numeric columns had 'NA' as values.
I fixed it by replacing NAs with 0 as:

```
Merged_df[is.na(Merged_df)] <-0   # must check for NA's in numeric column. If found, replace it with 0
```